# It's easy to robo-review questions and answers with comments!

Tags: bug, review-audits, deleted-answers

Just upvote a comment on the answer or question in question. You'll get a nice dialog box telling you that it's already deleted, effectively declaring it's an audit.

[image: The dialog...]

Comment: That doesn't look like an audit.  Audits generally display a zero score, not the actual score of minus 3, and I don't believe that comments are shown on audits.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5036449

Comment: Alright.  Well, all audits are really intended to do is get people to stop and think about what they're doing for a moment.  Seems like you did that.  Robo-reviewers are unlikely to upvote comments, and if they do, mission accomplished.

Comment: All abstractions are leaky, and audits even more so. Arguably, this one is a bit too blatant, though if you take the time to bother with the comments, you are already taking the time needed to do the right thing and even more.

Comment: Not all audits are like this. This is just a single type.

Comment: In this special case it’s even easier. Look at the gray user name and realize that the user which has answered 9 days ago has been deleted already. So you don’t need to click…